# How does the Satellite Networked Open Ground Station operate? How is it used?

Tags: cubesat, radio-communication, ground-station, public-involvement

[SatNOGS](https://satnogs.org/), the Satellite Networked Open Ground Station (mentioned [in this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24469/12102)) appears to be a distribution of independently maintained amateur DIY satellite receiving ground stations, linked by a single network.

How is it run? Do members log in via the internet and then reserve a time slot on whichever station they would like to use? I noticed that there are amateur radio callsigns associated with the stations. Does this suggest that *uplink* capabilities are available in addition to downlink?

[image]

Comment: I feel like the only reason they call it "SatNOGS" is so that they don't have to call it "SNOGS".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> members log in via the internet and then reserve a time slot on whichever
>   station they would like to use

Yeah,that's the idea.SatNOGS is primarily designed to receive data. In most  jurisdictions receiving data is allowed even by non-licensed individuals.

But.. having said that, if a station owner needs to send data to a satellite and has the needed hardware to do so (p.e. a radio or a Tx enabled SDR) the provided SatNOGS client software allows to the user open a console and transmit data to their satellite via their own ground-station.

Hope that helps.